# How do I change the color of a circular sector of a 2D stage in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a game where a rotating sprite can shine a line onto a black colored and circular arena. I want a circular sector of a certain angle to become white colored, depending on the sprite's orientation.

For example, if the sprite is at 90 degrees, the stage should look like this

[image]

What are the most efficient methods to achieve this?

Some details about the game that may be important to know:

- The sprite rotates at the center of the stage only and is not mobile.
- I'll likely make the arena a n-sided polygon, and the circular sectors will likely be triangular sectors. Then, a circle might overlay this polygon for make the arena look circular. (Not sure how I will be implementing this yet).

One idea I've considered is using cartesian coordinates to create triangles in canvas.

One difficulty I am having conceptually is determining the direction of my rotating sprite.

Comment: Sorry I don't get the idea .. maybe some illustrations would help to understand what exactly you are looking for

Comment: @derHugo Added a picture.

Comment: Is this for the entire stage or just for a mini map (radar)? You could probably just go with UI and a [Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Mask.html) in the latter case

Comment: @derHugo This is the arena, which is for the entire stage, although the area outside the circle will not be used.